# Is this z80 division algorithm broken?

Tags: division, z80

http://zxm.speccy.cz/data/Z80%20Bits.html#2.2

Input: HL = Dividend, C = Divisor, A = 0
Output: HL = Quotient, A = Remainder

```
add hl,hl       ; unroll 16 times
rla         ; ...
cp  c       ; ...
jr  c,$+4       ; ...
sub c       ; ...
inc l       ; ...
```

When I try it out, and set hl=$1200, a=0, c=$91, I get 0 in HL. Shouldn't it be $1f?

Comment: I believe that code can fail when c>7Fh and HL>00FFh. Suppose A==80h with an incoming bit of 1, then it'll roll over to A==01h. However, if you do a separate case where C>7Fh, you can optimise the first 8 iterations to: ld a,h \ ld h,l \ ld l,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is broken.  Here's the fixed version:

```
add hl,hl       ; unroll 16 times
rla             ; ...
jr  c,$+5       ; important!
cp  c           ; ...
jr  c,$+4       ; ...
sub c           ; ...
inc l           ; ...
```

If you shift `$1200` through `A` register you see that it never gets bigger than `$91`.  But once it reaches `$90` the next comparison needs to be against `$120` not `$20`.  The check for carry I added handles that case.

Looks like many of the examples on that page have similar problems.

Incidentally, `adc a,a` can be used in place of `rla` with no change in speed or size but with a big increase in clarity.  It makes it obvious that `AHL` is being treated as a 24 bit number.